# How to resign when I will be leaving in 2 weeks when working on-site with a client?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, consulting, transition

I work for a consulting company so they send me to different companies (clients). Currently, I am on a client (Only couple of weeks since I started), the client is super nice and takes me out for lunch and everything. The project I am working on is extremely important to the client and I am the team lead on the project.

How should I break the news to the client that I will be leaving my consulting company in 2 weeks?

Comment: Related - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/9074/2322

Comment: Related / maybe duplicate - [How do I brief a client I am leaving the company?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19814/how-do-i-brief-a-client-i-am-leaving-the-company)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Tell your consulting company -- give them notice -- and let your company's sales rep or business person tell the client. That's their job, not yours.

Is it a courtesy for you to tell the client?  Maybe you could argue that. But I don't agree. I do not think they should hear it from you. Seriously.

This business relationship doesn't belong to you personally, it belongs to your employer. They have the duty to figure out how to keep serving this client after you are gone, and make that part of their conversation with the client. If you tell the client, you make it harder for your company.

If you're careful, you can talk to the client right after your sales guy drops the hammer on him. But it would be unprofessional for you to drop the hammer on them yourself without having a service-continuity plan to present.

Comment: I completely agree with that! But don't you think it would be better if I tell the client and they hear it from me rather than they tell me "We heard that you are leaving the company"..

Comment: @johndoe, I think it is up to your company to decide how to break teh news. You can suggest when you give official notice, that you tell the client personally, but really it is their call. They amy want to go to them with a plan for who will replace you. If you tell them, ti might make the client nervous about how things will go and if the company rep tells them he may be prepared to mitigate thier fears in a way you wil not.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with Ollie Jones and HLGEM. I will let the client break the news. Thanks guys!

Comment: @johndoe, what do you think would happen if you tell them before you tell your boss, and they call your boss immediately before you can tell your boss? Tell your boss first. If your boss is good, then it will not come to "We heard that you are leaving the company", but your departure will be a "process" like it should be (i.e., all 3 of you talking together, you finishing up your work, maybe even handing over to someone else etc.).