# How to go on interviews while in resignation period from outsourcing firm, without offending the manager where I'm outsourced?

Tags: interviewing, resignation, notice-period, leave-of-absence

I only had my job last month and resigned today due to not liking my job. I submitted my resignation to my hr managers (im contractual) and Im going to leave the company where I was deployed on for good after 3 weeks from now.
Now I have pending and upcoming interviews that I am expecting this week and the next few days and I already asked for "leaves without pay" twice. MY manager seems not being impressed and rather annoyed as I am new and asked leaves twice already. I lied to her and told her I was sick but I went on interviews. She and my workmates are still unaware of my resignation and as much as possible I want to leave without telling them as I would not write my current work on my resume and wont like to talk about it.

How could I go to interviews during my resignation period without offending my supervisor or accepting my leave to go to interviews? Do I really have no choice but to tell her that I am resigning and would like to take a leave to go on interviews? I am running out of excuses just to go on interviews. She is really strict on approving leaves and tends to disapprove a lot of absences.

[Added] I am working via an outsourcing firm of a sister company and as per orientation I was told that I am employed to them - not to the company where I am deployed.
My job starts at 8am-5pm and all my interviews are also on weekdays between 8am-5pm so I cannot really go on these times. I just gave my resume on my agency HR after my shift and I think they will be the one informing them, not me.

Comment: Is this now a duplicate of "[Should I tell the client that I am resigning, if my consulting company isn't doing it?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/38827/)", which is itself a duplicate of "[How to resign when I will be leaving in 2 weeks when working on-site with a client?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30766)"?

Comment: Why are you asking a company that doesn't employ you for holiday time? Ask *your* employer and *inform* their client.

Comment: @NathanCooper In a now-deleted comment, the OP mentioned that this manager pesters him for the reason. I know, it is easy to say, "you don't have to bother what she thinks" (which is exactly what I said in a now-deleted comment!). It is not that easy to *do* in practice. As for your question, at a lot of these "client-based" companies, even though *your* manager officially approves your leaves, they do so after consulting with the client manager, so this situation is not so uncommon or unusual.

Comment: @Lilienthal It is not a duplicate of my question. This question's core issue is "how to attend interviews during notice period". The only thing common with my issue is that employer hasn't informed the client of the resignation. Even if the OP's employer does inform the client now, his core issue still remains.

Comment: @MaskedMan There's the difference though, you've left the sticky client interaction to your manager, which is probably best. Maybe it's different for client-based permies, but the behavior I'm suggesting is common among contractors because 'asking' for holiday can be used against them by the tax authorities, doesn't apply here though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resign when I will be leaving in 2 weeks when working on-site with a client?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/30766/how-to-resign-when-i-will-be-leaving-in-2-weeks-when-working-on-site-with-a-clie)

Answer (score 2):

> How could I go to interviews during my resignation period without
>   offending my supervisor or accepting my leave to go to interviews? Do
>   I really have no choice but to tell her that I am resigning and would
>   like to take a leave to go on interviews?

This is difficult, because you have already resigned, but that fact hasn't been announced to your supervisor. So your supervisor is rightfully expecting you to fulfill your contract and work, not take repeated times off. But in less than 3 weeks, your supervisor will know the truth one way or the other, and you will be gone.

Unfortunately, the interactions/notifications with the customer are the outsourcing company's responsibility, and not yours. If she only finds out about your leaving on your last day, she'll likely be offended anyway (hopefully in that case, her offense will be with the outsourcing company, and not with you personally).

If you don't want to offend her, ask permission from your employer (the outsourcing firm) to talk with your supervisor and let her know today that you will be leaving, and when.

If permission is granted (or if someone else in the outsourcing company informs your supervisor), then also ask your supervisor if you can take some time off between now and your last day to attend interviews. If your supervisor consents, then work with her to give her the hours she needs to transition away from you, and hopefully free up some hours for interviewing. That will avoid offending anyone.

If you don't have permission from your employer to announce your leaving to the supervisor, or if your supervisor doesn't give you permission to take time off from your contracted work, then you have no real choice other than to wait the 3 weeks and work out the remaining days. (If, as stated, you cannot interview after hours or on weekends.)

At that point 3 weeks from now you'll be unemployed and thus will have plenty of time for interviewing, and nobody can be offended.

Comment: Thanks. My agency isn't really doing anything and my recruiter hasn't even replied. She was "cold" when I passed her my resignation (which is to me really unethical move), now she hasn't replied to my messages. I do not plan to tell my company supervisor that I am resigning I am waiting for my agency to let them know that I am leaving. Since they haven't told them and I have 2 weeks left, and having this interview on Monday on a company I am still having problems how to tell my supervisor if my agency has't told her yet. I think I might have to do the "unexpected traffic excuse" for a half day